# Split a polygon with holes

Tags: openlayers, turf

I am unable to split a polygon with holes using a split line. A split line can start or end inside the hole of the polygon. For example, let's say there is a donut shape polygon with a hole in it, I want to cut it such that only one arm of the donut is split not the whole donut polygon itself. I have attached a few example images below - Left polygon in an image represents the original polygon and the red line represents a split line. Right polygon in an image represents the resulting polygon.

[image: Split Example 1]
[image: Split Example 2]

My existing code

```
polygonCut(polygon, line, idPrefix = 'cut_') {
    const THICK_LINE_UNITS = 'inches';
    const THICK_LINE_WIDTH = 2;
    let i, j, id, intersectPoints, lineCoords, forCut, forSelect;
    let thickLineString, thickLinePolygon, clipped, polyg, intersect;
    let polyCoords = [];
    let cutPolyGeoms = [];
    let cutFeatures = [];
    let offsetLine = [];
    let retVal = null;

    if ((polygon.type != 'Polygon' && polygon.type != 'MultiPolygon') || line.type != 'LineString') {
        return retVal;
    }

    if (typeof idPrefix === 'undefined') {
        idPrefix = '';
    }

    intersectPoints = lineIntersect(polygon, line);
    if (intersectPoints.features.length == 0) {
        return retVal;
    }

    lineCoords = getCoords(line);

    // return null if line start or end is within any polygon
    if (
        booleanWithin(point(lineCoords[0]), polygon) ||
        booleanWithin(point(lineCoords[lineCoords.length - 1]), polygon)
    ) {
        return retVal;
    }

    offsetLine[0] = lineOffset(line, THICK_LINE_WIDTH, { units: THICK_LINE_UNITS });
    offsetLine[1] = lineOffset(line, -THICK_LINE_WIDTH, { units: THICK_LINE_UNITS });

    for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        forCut = i;
        forSelect = (i + 1) % 2;
        polyCoords = [];

        for (j = 0; j < line.coordinates.length; j++) {
            polyCoords.push(line.coordinates[j]);
        }
        for (j = offsetLine[forCut].geometry.coordinates.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            polyCoords.push(offsetLine[forCut].geometry.coordinates[j]);
        }
        polyCoords.push(line.coordinates[0]);

        thickLineString = lineString(polyCoords);
        thickLinePolygon = lineToPolygon(thickLineString);
        clipped = difference(polygon, thickLinePolygon);

        cutPolyGeoms = [];
        for (j = 0; j < clipped.geometry.coordinates.length; j++) {
            polyg = turfPolygon(clipped.geometry.coordinates[j]);
            intersect = lineIntersect(polyg, offsetLine[forSelect]);
            if (intersect.features.length > 0) {
                cutPolyGeoms.push(polyg.geometry.coordinates);
            }
        }

        cutPolyGeoms.forEach(function (geometry, index) {
            id = idPrefix + (i + 1) + '.' + (index + 1);
            cutFeatures.push(turfPolygon(geometry, { id: id }));
        });
    }
    if (cutFeatures.length > 0) {
        retVal = featureCollection(cutFeatures);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Hey @TomazicM I have added the code that I am using to split the normal polygon.

Comment: It is probably best done using a third-party utility such as turf https://turfjs.org/docs/#difference  Expand the line into a narrow polygon and use it as the second argument in a difference request.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike! that's definitely worth a shot

Comment: Topologically speaking, the operations you are showing do ***not*** split the features **by line**. A "split" results in two features. Your graphics show a buffered line *erasing* part of a polygon, resulting in one polygon. If the line doesn't partition the feature, it's not a valid split operation.

Comment: @Mike, the solution that you suggested worked perfectly. Thanks again!